# How can I prevent VS2012 from running IIS Express for any debug?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

I am running VS2012 (Ultimate version 11.0.51106.01 Update 01) and do have a website project along with some console, WPF and WCF server projects. My normal debugging runs a non website project and rarely do I debug the website project.

Any debugging however, always starts IIS Express. How can I prevent that? The website project "Web" tab forces me to select some web server and "IIS Express" is currently selected, but I don't want it to start unless I'm debugging the website. Seems like this started happening after some recent VS2012 maintenance as I don't remember it happening before about a few weeks ago. Now getting old.

Is this a VS2012 bug that any debugging fires up IIS Express?

Anyway to not start it when I debug a WPF or console app?

Comment: This is not a well tested scenario, the vast majority of programmers just use a separate solution.  I don't see this when I quickly try.  Post your issue to connect.microsoft.com, they'll at least need your solution and project files to have a shot at diagnosing this.

Comment: I like the idea of a separate solution in the meantime. Thanks!

Comment: Still happens in VS2013 Update 4. Anyone have any more input? This solution does have mixed apps - web, wpf, service. Don't see any reason this should happen by default though when debugging a non web app. Thx.